# passing a variable to all templates from views.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

is that possible in django to pass a variable from views.py to all html templates.

for example: i have a variable "baseURL" it will be used in all templates. the reason is "baseURL" keeps on changing and if i change this in one place it should be reflected in all the places

Answer (score 5):

This is what [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) are for.

```
def base_url(request):
    return {'base_url': settings.BASE_URL}
```

and add `path.to.module.base_url` to the TEMPLATES `context_processors` list in your settings; now you can do `{{ base_url }}` in any template.

Comment: the "baseURL" contain a string of url (like example.com) where do i declare that, in your solution.?

Comment: @mymail you can put it inside any app as a new file.

Comment: Sounds like a setting; it should go in settings.py.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def search_isbn(request):
    var = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        var = 500
    return render('results.html', {'var':var})
```